# Animating newly created objects with different keyframes values

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So I'm trying to make simple animation. When you press somewhere inside blue container, a circle should be created in this place and then go up. After some research I found how to put JS values into keyframes, but it's changing values for every object not just for freshly created. If you run snipped and press somewhere high and then somewhere low you will see what I'm talking about.

I found some AWESOME solution with [Raphael](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/QZW3Q/) library, but I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make something like this in JS. Is it even possible? How?

```js
var bubble = {
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    size: 0
  };

var aquarium = document.getElementById("container");

var ss = document.styleSheets;
var keyframesRule = [];
function findAnimation(animName) { //function to find keyframes and insert replace values in them
  for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
      if (window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE == ss[i].cssRules[j].type && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == animName) {
        keyframesRule.push(ss[i].cssRules[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return keyframesRule;
}


function changeAnimation (nameAnim) {  //changing top value to cursor position when clicked
  var keyframesArr = findAnimation(nameAnim);
  for (var i = 0; i < keyframesArr.length; i++) {
    keyframesArr[i].deleteRule("0%");
    keyframesArr[i].appendRule("0% {top: " + bubble.posY + "px}");
  }
}


function createBubble(e) {
  "use strict";
  bubble.posX = e.clientX;
  bubble.posY = e.clientY;
  bubble.size = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  var bubbleCircle = document.createElement("div");
  aquarium.appendChild(bubbleCircle);
  bubbleCircle.className = "bubble";
  var bubbleStyle = bubbleCircle.style;
  bubbleStyle.width = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.height = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.borderRadius = (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  //bubbleStyle.top = bubble.posY - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleStyle.left = bubble.posX - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  changeAnimation("moveUp");
  bubbleCircle.className += " animate";
}

aquarium.addEventListener("click", createBubble);
//console.log(bubble);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(20,255,200);
}

#surface {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
}

.bubble {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.animate {
  animation: moveUp 5s linear;//cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-animation: moveUp 5s linear;//cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
}


@keyframes moveUp{
  0% {
    top: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUp{
  0% {
    top: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div id="surface">
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, so what are you trying to achieve here ? Whenever someone clicks inside of the blue container, a bubble should go up. Is that it ?

Comment: I do honestly not see why you want to change the keyframe in javascript. What is wrong about removing a class and adding another to change the animation? This will be more reliable and way better to read and understand.

Comment: All your animated bubbles are being animated by the same animation (`moveUp`), so when you update the `0%` of that animation, it updates every animated bubble. You may want to dynamically add a new animation created as css on each bubble as it is created.

Comment: As I said, I'm just learning and changing keyframe in javascript was the only solution I found for my problem. Right now I'm creating a bubble in cursor place and then apply class "animate" for this bubble, which is also dependent on cursor position. If I'm not seeing obvious solution, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @arbuthnott this is exactly a question I'm looking the answer for. How to dynamically add a NEW animation to each bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. What I did:

- Remove your functions `changeAnimation ()` and `findAnimation()` - we don't need them
- Update the keyframe to look like - only take care for the **100%**

  `@keyframes moveUp { 100% {top: 80px;} }`
- Assign `top` of the new bubble with the `clientY` value
- After 5 seconds set `top` of the bubble to the offset of the `#container`(*80px*) - exactly when animation is over to keep the position of the bubble, otherwise it will return to initial position

```js
var bubble = {
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  size: 0
};

var aquarium = document.getElementById("container");

function createBubble(e) {
  "use strict";
  bubble.posX = e.clientX;
  bubble.posY = e.clientY;

  bubble.size = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  var bubbleCircle = document.createElement("div");
  aquarium.appendChild(bubbleCircle);
  bubbleCircle.className = "bubble";
  var bubbleStyle = bubbleCircle.style;
  bubbleStyle.width = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.height = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.borderRadius = (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleStyle.top = bubble.posY - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleStyle.left = bubble.posX - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleCircle.className += " animate";

  // The following code will take care to reset top to the top 
  // offset of #container which is 80px, otherwise circle will return to 
  // the position of which it was created
  (function(style) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      style.top = '80px';
    }, 5000);
  })(bubbleStyle);
}

aquarium.addEventListener("click", createBubble);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(20, 255, 200);
}

#surface {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

.bubble {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.animate {
  animation: moveUp 5s linear;
  /*cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);*/
  -webkit-animation: moveUp 5s linear;
  /*cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);*/
}

@keyframes moveUp {
  100% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  100% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="surface"></div>
</body>
```

The problem about your code was that it is globally changing the **@keyframes moveUp** which is causing all the bubbles to move.

Comment: This looks exactly as something I was trying to do. I'll try to wrap my mind around it later today. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, this is not creating new **@keyframes** for each bubble as asked, but I think this will be more efficient :)

Comment: As I said. I'm just learning. And right now I'm making up a challenges for myself. But because my knowledge is small, sometimes I'm too focused on using screwdriver to nail nails, when there is better solution I didn't  think off.

Comment: **Stackoverflow** is a great place to learn coding. I'm sure that you will learn new stuff everyday and if you push yourself you will become a great coder :)

Comment: Yup, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Funny thing thou. Two days ago I was trying to do something like this with transitions, as @nathan-p propose in the other comment, but I stucked at the end, as all my bubbles ended in starting position :) I didn't have last part you presented with setTimeout! Also it took me a while with that function, as I have never seen declaration as this. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for explanation - in the last part I used [**self invoking function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), I used it because `setTimeout` is async and we needed to keep a reference to the `style` object. [**Self invoking function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) are also used as [**Closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Closures) which can be used to keep some variables visible in the scope until async operation is done

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you're updating keyframes which are applied to all bubbles. I tried another way of doing it by using [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and changing the `top` position *after* the element was added to the DOM (otherwise it wouldn't be animated).

The main problem here is to wait the element to be added to the DOM. I tried using [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but it seems to be called before the element is actually added to the DOM (or at least rendered). So the only way I found is using a timeout which will simulate this waiting, although there must be a better one (because it may be called too early, causing the bubble to directly stick to the top), which I would be happy to hear about.

```js
var bubble = {
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  size: 0
};

var aquarium = document.getElementById("container");

function createBubble(e) {
  "use strict";
  bubble.posX = e.clientX;
  bubble.posY = e.clientY;
  bubble.size = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  var bubbleCircle = document.createElement("div");
  aquarium.appendChild(bubbleCircle);

  bubbleCircle.classList.add("bubble");
  var bubbleStyle = bubbleCircle.style;

  bubbleStyle.width = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.height = bubble.size + "px";
  bubbleStyle.borderRadius = (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleStyle.top = bubble.posY - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";
  bubbleStyle.left = bubble.posX - (bubble.size / 2) + "px";

  setTimeout(function() {
    bubbleCircle.classList.add("moveUp");
  }, 50);
}

aquarium.addEventListener("click", createBubble);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(20, 255, 200);
}

#surface {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

.bubble {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  transition: 5s;
}

.moveUp {
  top: 80px !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div id="surface">

  </div>
</body>
```

Also, I used the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) object instead of `className += ...` because it is more reliable.

Comment: Good solution +1

Comment: Thank you. I will try to get into your solution later today. It's working as intended but I was interested in using keyframes as it can give more flexibility. But still it's something new to know. Thanks.